# trying to find all permissions a User has in liferay 6.2 and return a JSON object

Tags: json, permissions, liferay-6, user-permissions

I am very inexperienced with Liferay 6.2. I have searched through the documentation, but cannot find an answer.

I am trying to find all the Users permissions and return them in a JSON object. So far, all I can find is the permission checker,

> boolean  hasOwnerPermission(long companyId, String name, long primKey, long ownerId, String actionId)
>   Returns true if the user is the owner of the resource and has permission to perform the action.
>
> boolean    hasOwnerPermission(long companyId, String name, String primKey, long ownerId, String actionId)
>              Returns true if the user is the owner of the resource and has permission to perform the action.
>
> boolean    hasPermission(long groupId, String name, long primKey, String actionId)
>             Returns true if the user has permission to perform the action on the resource.
>
> boolean    hasPermission(long groupId, String name, String primKey, String actionId)
>             Returns true if the user has permission to perform the action on the resource.
>
> boolean    hasUserPermission(long groupId, String name, String primKey, String actionId, boolean checkAdmin)
>             Returns true if the user has permission to perform the action on the resource without using guest permissions.

But this only checks to see if a user has a permission.

I am after a list of all permissions. does Liferay support this functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.getResourcePermission();
```

to find permission for particular resource.